# In Resque, is there a way to bump a job to the top of queue?

Tags: resque

I have a job within a queue that has a higher priority than other jobs in that queue. Is there a mechanism in Resque by which I can move this job to the top of the queue?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an adhoc bump you can use redis from a ruby/rails console as

```rb
class_looking_for = "MyWorker"
args_looking_for = [1234, {"foo" => "bar"}]
queue = "foo"
redis = Resque.redis
key = "queue:#{queue}"

redis.llen(key).times do |n|
  value = redis.lindex(key, n)
  job = Resque.decode(value)
  if job["class"] == class_looking_for && job["args"] == args_looking_for
    redis.lrem(key, value)
    redis.lpush(value)
    break
  end
end
```

This will loop through the keys in the redis list used by redis to store the given `queue` and check if it matches given `class_looking_for` and `args_looking_for`, adjust the filter to your needs (the `job` looks like this `{"class"=>"PieCutWorker", "args"=>[42529, "heart shape"]}`), once the right job is found, it will be removed from the queue and then appended to it. Then it's ready to picked up by the next available worker.

But, if you need this as a system rule, as `job "X" always needs to run right away`, then you are better off creating a new queue for that job and either initialize redis workers as

```
$ QUEUE=important,something,bulk rake resque:work
```

as the QUEUE param uses the order of the comma separated strings to define priority.